# Dynamically show Razor ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a few validation that I had on top of the page.  I wanted to dynamically show the horizontal rows only if there are errors.

```
<tr><td colspan="4">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldCitizenVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })</td></tr>
```

what I wanted to do is that in Razor syntax have something like this

```
@if (model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification isinvalid)
{  
    <tr><td colspan="4">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })</td></tr>
 }
```

I am trying to find out the syntax in razor that I can dynamically show the Horizontal Rows.  Any suggestion??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the error message only if there are errors.You can use `ModelState` validation through `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState`.

Example:

```
@if (!ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't treat them as separate rows. By default, the validation message will only be displayed if there's a reason for it to be. As a result, you can just do:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tempHouseHoldCitizenVerification, null, new { style = "color:red" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then, whichever one has the validation error will display, while the other will not. No need to check for errors manually.

Comment: If *both* errors will display at the same time, then simply wrap them both individually in some block-level tag like `div`.